# Can sec^2 be re-written as 2sec?

Tags: calculus, trigonometry

I have forgotten if it can or cannot. Please help me remember! 
**my attempt**

> So I've got equation f(x)=tan x/4 on interval (0,2pi) and I found its' 2nd derivative f"(x)=sec^2(x/4)tan(x/4)/8. I'm wondering if sec^2 can be re-written as 2sec to make it easier to solve for x when i equal it to 0.

Comment: No. If we had $\sec^2(x) = 2\sec(x)$ then $\sec(x)$ would have to be $0$ or $2$ everywhere. This is not the case. To solve $f'(x) = 0$ notice that $\sec^2(x)\tan(x/4) = 0$ implies that we either have $\sec(x)=0$ or $\tan(x/4)=0$.

Comment: Try a couple of values for $x$.  Is $2\sec{\pi}=\sec^2{\pi}$?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$\sec^2(x)=\frac{1}{\cos^2(x)}\ne\frac{2}{\cos(x)}$$